# Algorithms Run time Complexity

Tags: c#

Hi I suppose to write a program that show the run time complixity
I solved two but can't solve the third the code is :

```
{
class Program
{
    /* static long F1(long n)
     {
         long sum = 0;
         for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
         {
             for (int j = 1; j <=n*n; j++)
             {
                 for (int m = 1; m <=j; m++)
                 {
                     sum = sum + 1;
                 }
             }
         }
         return sum;
      }
    static long F2(long n)
     {
         long sum = 0;
         for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++)
         {
             for (int j = 1; j <= n ; j++)
             {
                 for (int m = 1; m <= j; m++)
                 {
                     sum = sum + 1;
                 }
             }
         }
         return sum;

     }*/
  static long F3(long n)
  {
      long prod = 1;
      long m;
      long i = 2;
      long s = n;
      while (n >= 1)
      {
          m = 1;
          while (m <= n)
          {
              prod = prod * 2;
              m = m + 1;
          }
          n = s / i;
          i++;
      }
         return prod;

     }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // Console.WriteLine(F1(100));
       // Console.WriteLine(F2(2200));
     Console.WriteLine(F3(10000));
        long x; 
        DateTime d1=DateTime.Now;
        x=d1.Ticks;
     // F1(600);  
    //    F2(2200);
        F3(1000);
        DateTime d2=DateTime.Now;
        x=(d2.Ticks-x)/10000000;
        Console.WriteLine("x=" + x.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

```
now the correct answers that F3 should show are

300000000   0   5
400000000   0   4
500000000   0   7
```

but all what i got is o o o

while the F2 and F1 are showing right answers can any one help

Comment: Can you detail what exactly your program is supposed to do?

Comment: Determine RunTime Complexity for each of the following  functions and the code should show the results i posted

Comment: You forgot to say what problem you are trying to solve. You saved some time with less typing, but you are wasting time of all readers.

Comment: For your second question: System.out.println("300000000   0   5\n400000000   0   4\n500000000   0   7");

Comment: Is it only me that finds the question a bit confusing?

The main method contains two WriteLine() calls, but the expected output contains three lines.

The WriteLine() calls print one value each, and one of the values is prepended with "x=", but each line in the expected output contains three values, and the "x=" is nowhere to be seen.


I suggest you specify what that expected output is more precisely. At least I am having a hard time understanding what you mean.

Comment: @Alderath no the program shows two calcualted rsults the for example the 0 and 4 the big number is the one Im passing to the function , I made two mistakes here one was solved as Mr. Jack explained and in the function it self I changed it to FORs instead of WHILEs and its workin fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wonder is: isn't it just a matter of integer division?

I mean here: `x=(d2.Ticks-x)/10000000;`

Note: I'm not practical with C#, it's just an hypothesis

Comment: the problem with the othe functions F1 and F2 every thing is fine but with F3 Im getting wronge answers

Comment: Maybe because F1 and F2 last more than 10000000 ticks while all runs of F3 are shorter: this will cause the output of three 0s.

Comment: @Jack: Could `F3` be `pow(2,n)`?

Comment: A float value like 10000000.0, but as stated I'm not fond of C#.. mine was just a guess, since when integer division is used these errors are likely to occur..

Comment: I see that Mau is using this conversation to update his answer :)

Comment: @jack but still wronge results now Im getting weird numbers, I hate ADS

Comment: Of course you are, `x` is defined as a long. You should treat everything as a float..

Comment: I did change the long to double thing but still

Answer (score 0):

```
 x=(d2.Ticks-x)/10000000
```

is where the problem lies. F3 runs for less than a second and you are doing integer divisions: remember that `900/1000 == 0`.

A simple (rather unelegant) fix is to do a floating point division:

```
 x=(d2.Ticks-x)/10000000.0
```

You might want to use `TimeSpan`s intead, which are made to measure elapsed time:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

// Do stuff

DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan elapsed = end - start;
double secondsElapsed = elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```